# RECURSIVE function that will sum digits of input

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, recursion

Trying to write a piece of code that will sum the digits of a number. Also I should add that I want the program to keep summing the digits until the sum is only 1 digit.

For example, if you start with 1969, it should first add 1+9+6+9 to get 25. Since the value 25 has more than a single digit, it should repeat the operation to obtain 7 as a final answer.

Was just wondering how I could pull this off and possibly make it recursive as well. This is what I have so far

```
def sum_digits3(n):
     r = 0
     while n:
         r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
     return r
```

Comment: see: [Digital Root without loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40875066/6732794) (edit: removed other link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert back and forth between strings and ints, make use of sum().

```
>>> def foo(n):
    n = str(n)
    if len(n) == 1:
        return int(n)
    return foo(sum(int(c) for c in n))

>>> foo(1969)
7
>>>
```

---

```
def foo(n):
    n = str(n)
    if len(n) == 1:
        return int(n)
    return foo(sum(int(c) for c in n))
```

Comment: @leaf, sorry, copy and pastes from Idle - type it in Idle that way and it  works.  An Idle feature I could live without.

Comment: That's fine. But for some reason, its running fine in my IDLE to. I guess your intention is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as involving explicitly the recursion.

```
def sum_digits3(n):
    r = 0
    while n:
        r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
    if len(str(r))>1:
        return sum_digits3(r)
    return r
```

But i must admit that i am going to read the links given by suspicious dog. And the answer of wwii is smarter than mine.