# How to write a function which takes a string and turns into a single digit?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, function

I want to write a function which turns a string into a single digit. Every letter has a number value and at the end, it should return the sum of letters but if it's bigger than 10 it should take the sum of the digits until it finds between 0 and 10. For example, if result 99 it should firstly take 9+9 = 18 then it should take 1 + 8 and the final answer must be 9.

```
def name_numerology(name):

    letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    numbers = '1234567891234567891234567812345678912345678912345678'

    toq = list(zip(letters, numbers))
    sie = []
    for i in name:
        if i in letters:
            sie.append(toq[letters.index(i)])
    ruk = []
    for i, k in sie:
        ruk.append(int(k))
    zu = sum(ruk)
    da = [i for i in str(zu)]
    re = [int(i) for i in da]
    return sum(re)

print(name_numerology('rasmuuuuuuuu'))
```

output is:

```
12
```

I stucked here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, I've added a while loop to return numbers less than 10 and doesn't evaluate to "None", it will run the while loop until those conditions are met:

```
def name_numerology(name):

    letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    numbers = '1234567891234567891234567812345678912345678912345678'

    toq = list(zip(letters, numbers))
    sie = []
    for i in name:
        if i in letters:
            sie.append(toq[letters.index(i)])
    ruk = []
    for i, k in sie:
        ruk.append(int(k))
    zu = sum(ruk)
    while zu > 10:

        da = [i for i in str(zu)]
        re = [int(i) for i in da]
        zu = sum(re)
        if zu is not None and zu < 10:
            return zu
    return zu # will handle if number is less than 10 prior to while loop, otherwise "None"

print(name_numerology('rasmuuuuuuuu'))
# 3
print(name_numerology('GHKLLLlllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm'))
# 4
print(name_numerology('A'))
# 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is overcomplicated. You can consider only lowercase letters, since the mappings for lower and upper cases are identical. Use a dictionary instead of a list for O(1) lookup. Then use [this O(1) recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40875151/9209546) for the digital root.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def name_numerology(name):
    letter_num_map = {v: k % 9 + 1 for k, v in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}
    num = sum(map(letter_num_map.__getitem__, name.casefold()))    
    return (num - 1) % 9 + 1

res = name_numerology('hello')  # 7
```

Non-letters can easily be removed via `filter` + `str.isalpha`:

```
def name_numerology(name):
    letter_num_map = {v: k % 9 + 1 for k, v in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}
    modified_string = filter(str.isalpha, name.casefold())
    num = sum(map(letter_num_map.__getitem__, modified_string))
    return (num - 1) % 9 + 1

res = name_numerology('hello ? 234 ')  # 7
```

Comment: Appreciated. But I forgot the mention about the function must handle if the input is not a string and must convert it into a string. Also, it must other characters which are not in my letters object. My function is able to handle this problem but I couldn't complete it.

Comment: @BirkanEmrem, That's an edge case that can easily be handled, see update.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the [rule of nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rule_of_nines_(mathematics)&redirect=no). A more direct way :

```
import collections
mapping = collections.defaultdict(int,( (k,int(i)) for k,i in zip(letters,numbers) ) )

def encode(string):
    res=sum( (mapping[c] for c in string) ) % 9 
    return res if res else 9


In [14]: encode('rasmuuuuuuuu')
3
In [15]: encode('Hello$')
7
```

`defaultdict` maps unknown caracters on 0.

Comment: For a string that maps to `333`, the correct answer would be `9`, but your code would return `0`

Comment: @PH : Oups. Thanks. edited.

Answer (score 0):

There are [easier ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765790/797495) of achieve what you need, but based on your example, you can use:

```
def name_numerology(name):

    letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    numbers = '1234567891234567891234567812345678912345678912345678'

    toq = list(zip(letters, numbers))
    sie = []
    for i in name:
        if i in letters:
            sie.append(toq[letters.index(i)])
    ruk = []
    for i, k in sie:
        ruk.append(int(k))
    zu = sum(ruk)
    da = [i for i in str(zu)]
    re = [int(i) for i in da]
    if len(str(sum(re))) == 2:
        return int(str(sum(re))[0]) + int(str(sum(re))[1])
    else:
        return int(str(sum(re)))

print(name_numerology('rasmuuuuuuuu'))
# 3
```

---

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QLS)